# How to deserialize a Map<String, Object> into POJO?

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, gson

I have a Map<String, Object> which contains a deserialized form of JSON.  I would like to deserialize this into the fields of a POJO.

I can perform this using Gson by serializing the Map into a JSON string and then deserializing the JSON string into the POJO, but this is inefficient (see example below).  How can I perform this without the middle step?

The solution should preferably use either Gson or Jackson, as they're already in use by the project.

Example code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Object> innermap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        innermap.put("number", 234);
        innermap.put("string", "bar");
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("number", 123);
        map.put("string", "foo");
        map.put("pojo2", innermap);

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        // How to perform this without JSON serialization?
        String json = gson.toJson(map);
        MyPojo pojo = gson.fromJson(json, MyPojo.class);

        System.out.println(pojo);
    }
}


class MyPojo {
    private int number;
    private String string;
    private MyPojo pojo2;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyPojo[number=" + number + ", string=" + string + ", pojo2=" + pojo2 + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a Map<String, String> to a POJO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428817/convert-a-mapstring-string-to-a-pojo)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Using Gson, you can turn your Map into a `JsonElement`, which you can then parse in exactly the same way using `fromJson`:

```
JsonElement jsonElement = gson.toJsonTree(map);
MyPojo pojo = gson.fromJson(jsonElement, MyPojo.class);
```

This is similar to the `toJson` method that you are already using, except that it avoids writing the JSON String representation and then parsing that JSON String back into a JsonElement before converting it to your class.

Comment: Just what I was looking for.  The Jackson answer by Michal works as well, but we're using Gson more, so it fits our needs better.

Answer (score 26):

In `Jackson` you can use [convertValue](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#convertValue-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Class-) method. See below example:

```
mapper.convertValue(map, MyPojo.class);
```

Comment: hey ,I'm  not able to open the link , can you share new working one ?

Comment: @GurkiratSinghGuliani, I updated link. Now it points to version `2.12`

Answer (score 10):

You can use jackson library for convert map object to direct POJO.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("id", "5");
map.put("name", "Bob");
map.put("age", "23");
map.put("savings", "2500.39");

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyPojo pojo = mapper.convertValue(map, MyPojo.class);
```

Comment: The question was about Map<String, Object>

Answer (score -1):

You can directly construct MyPojo by giving it the map.
Something like

```
MyPojo pojo = new MyPojo(map);
```

And declaring an according constructor :

```
public MyPojo(Map<String, Object> map){
  this.number=map.get("number");
  this.string=map.get("string");
  this.pojo2=new MyPojo(); // I don't know if this is possible
  this.pojo2.string=map.get("pojo2").get("string");
  this.pojo2.number=map.get("pojo2").get("number");
}
```

Comment: I want to avoid explicit mapping, since I have many different classes I want to deserialize from.