# Fill Java object from Map<String, List<String>>

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization

the problem is to fill Java object fields both of java standart types(Long, Boolean, etc.) and collections of those from a `Map<String, List<String>>`.

Inspecting target object's fields via reflecton one can see which field is a `Collection` and which is not. In second case if Map element has a single value one can use something like BeanUtils to set such fields:

```
BeanUtils.setProperty(bean, name, stringList.get(0));
```

But in first case I don't have idea how to determine a type of collection(except of sequentially checking if it is List, Set, Map) and type of it's elements. Simple

```
BeanUtils.setProperty(bean, name, stringList);
```

will be valid only if target field type is a `List<String>`.

But the Jackson library succesfully solves the same problem. For example, consider class:

```
public static class TestObject {
    private int integerField;
    private String stringField;
    private List<String> stringList;
    private List<Integer> intList;

    ...getters...setters...
}
```

Now it can be filled with content using Jackson library:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    TestObject obj = mapper.readValue("{" +
            "\"stringField\": \"stringValue\", " +
            "\"integerField\": 42, " +
            "\"stringList\":[\"1\", \"2\", \"3\"]," +
            "\"intList\":[3, 2, 1]" +
            "}", TestObject.class);
```

Works perfect. So my question: is there way to use a library such Jackson for solving my problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try converting your Map<String, List<String>> to a JSON object, and then deseriliazing it with Jackson? However, you'd need to manually process your map, to replace all single-element lists with the elements.

Comment: Thanks, that would work, but I guess it's possible to directly convert my structure to something that jackson would work with.

Comment: Here's something: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428817/convert-a-mapstring-string-to-a-pojo