# Can't find a codec for my class

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have simple class named Signal. Class looks as follows:

```
public class Signal {
    private String id;
    private Date timestamp;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Date getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }
    public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```

I am trying to insert signal in MongoDB (v3.4). I am using the following method to insert:

```
public boolean xyz(Signal signal) {
            try {
                DatabaseConnection databaseConnection =DatabaseConnection.getInstance();
                MongoClient mongoClient = databaseConnection.getMongoClient();
                MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("myDb"); 
                MongoCollection<Signal> collection = db.getCollection("myCollection", Signal.class);
                collection.insertOne(signal);

                return true;
            } catch (Exception e){
                logger.error("Error", e);
                return false;
            }

        }
```

I am getting the following exception:

> org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find
>   a codec for class in.co.mysite.webapi.models.Signal.

I checked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39433775/mongodb-java-inserting-throws-org-bson-codecs-configuration-codecconfigurationex) but insertion code is different. I took the hint from answer and modified my method but it doesn't look clean. Modified method is as follows:

```
public boolean xyz(Signal signal) {
        try {
            DatabaseConnection databaseConnection =DatabaseConnection.getInstance();
            MongoClient mongoClient = databaseConnection.getMongoClient();
            MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("myDb"); 
            MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("myCollection");

            Document doc = new Document();

            doc.put("id", signal.getId());
            doc.put("timestamp", signal.getTimestamp());
            doc.put("_id", new ObjectId().toString());

            collection.insertOne(doc);

            return true;
        } catch (Exception e){
            logger.error("Error", e);
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: You can try defining your custom `Codec` as well for the model.

Comment: @nullpointer I havent wrote Codec for pojo class. Will you please point me in right direction?

Comment: That was a hint, I am sure you know you can try and if something doesn't work there, come back to SO ;)

Answer (score 14):

You need to configure a `CodecRegistry` which will manage the translation from bson to your pojos:

```
MongoClientURI connectionString = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017");
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);
CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry = org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(), org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries.fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build()));
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("testdb").withCodecRegistry(pojoCodecRegistry);
```

PS: You could statically import `org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries.fromRegistries` and `org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries.fromProviders`.

A full example could be found in [github](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/driver-sync/src/examples/tour/PojoQuickTour.java).
The [Mongodb java driver documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.8/driver/getting-started/quick-start-pojo/) contains also an article about managing pojos (The link is for the 3.8.0 driver version).

Answer (score 3):

Follow the quick start guide for POJO. You need to register the codec to make the translation of your POJOs (Plain Old Java Object) to/from BSON:
http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.7/driver/getting-started/quick-start-pojo/

Answer (score 3):

Documentation:
[MongoDB Driver Quick Start - POJOs](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.7/driver/getting-started/quick-start-pojo/)

After following the above document, if you are still getting error, then

you could be using a **generic document** inside your **collection**  like

```
class DocStore {
  String docId:
  String docType;
  Object document; // this will cause the BSON cast to throw a codec error
  Map<String, Object> document; // this won't
}
```

And still, you would want to cast your document 
from **POJO** to **Map**

[mkyong](https://mkyong.com/java/java-convert-object-to-map-example/) comes to rescue.

As for the fetch, it works as expected but you might want to cast from Map to your POJO as a post-processing step, we can find some good answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428817/convert-a-mapstring-string-to-a-pojo)

Hope it helps! ️

Answer (score 1):

Have you annotated your Java class? Looks like you need a @Entity above your class and @Id above your ID field.

Comment: I purposely didnt annotate because "signal" is technically not an entity according to my architecture/logic.

Comment: But your saving it with Morphia as an entity and it is the top level representation of a collection, so it is an entity in this context