# Gson Map<String, Any> to Object

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gson

What's the most efficient way to convert a JSON in the format of `Map<String, Any>` to the corresponding java/kotlin object?

For now I have to use it like that which seems like a stupid implementation.

`gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(mapToConvert), typeToken)`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a [`JsonElement`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html):

```
val jsonElement = gson.toJsonTree(map)
val foo = gson.fromJson(jsonElement, Foo::class.java)
```

You can make this look nicer with a utility function:

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> Gson.fromMap(map: Map<*, *>) {
    return fromJson(toJsonTree(map), T::class.java)
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
gson.fromMap<Foo>(map)
```

Comment: well, thats just the same thing, my goal is to avoid that one extra gson conversion

Comment: @martynmlostekk No, it is not, `toJson` converts it to a string. `toJsonTree` converts it into an in-memory representation of a JSON element tree ([`JsonElement`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html)). I see what you mean though and I do not think Gson has a mechanism to do this. [This is more directly possible with Jackson though](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16430704/7366707).

Comment: okay, thats not exactly what i need but in this case (using with retrofit) i can at least reduce it by the gson conversions by 1 (to a total of 2). thanks. will mark it as solution if nobody else will answer within couple of days