# Set value of POJO properties that exist in both POJO and Map

Tags: java

How do I set the values of POJO properties that exist in both POJO and Map objects?

For example, I have this POJO class:

```
public class User {
   private int id;
   private String name;
   private String address;

   // getters/setters
}

User user = new User();
user.setId(1);
user.setName("Julez");
user.setAddress("Southwood City");
```

And I have this Map:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("address", "Eastwood City");
```

Since **User** class has **address**, and Map has key **address**, I'd like to set the value of **address** as **Eastwood City**. There might be a possibility that the **Map** would also have key **id**, **name**, a combination of **two** or all of the **User** properties.

Edit: User object has already been created and all properties have values. In the above example, the **address** ***Eastwood City*** should be replaced by ***Southwood City***.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a Map<String, String> to a POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428817/convert-a-mapstring-string-to-a-pojo)

Comment: @GauravRai1512, pardon. I missed some important things. The `user` object should have been created and its properties have values, which means one or more of these properties would be updated depending on available key/value in the `map` object.