# Convert map to object

Tags: android, kotlin

I create `Map <String,List<Object>>`

```
 val groupListByUserName = sharedList.groupBy { it -> it.user.displayName }
```

this function groupBy list by userNAme. Next I create model

```
data class SharedList(val userName:String,val sharedList: List<MovieMyList>)
```

I want add data with map to list and I don't konw how. Do you have any idea how make this?

Comment: Hi! I think that I can't understand what you want to achieve. Could you provide an example? In addiction, you should post some experiments you made to achieve your goal.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a Map<String, String> to a POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428817/convert-a-mapstring-string-to-a-pojo)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want to convert the `Map<String, List<MovieMyList>>` into a `List<SharedList>`, is that it?

```
val groupListByUserName = sharedList.groupBy { it -> it.user.displayName }
val sharedLists = groupListByUserName.map { (user, movies) -> SharedList(user, movies) }
```

Note that here, the parentheses in the lambda are important: calling `map` on a `Map` will deal with the map's entries, each composed of a key and a value. Using the parentheses performs [destructuring](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html) on the entry to directly access its key and value.

Comment: you can omit `it ->`: `.groupBy { it.user.displayName }` :)

Comment: @WilliMentzel Yes of course, I just copied the OP's line as a reminder, in order to show what he has and what to do from there. That's why I prefer to keep it as-is.