# Converting a Map<String, String> to a Value type with Jedis

Tags: java, redis, objectmapper, jedis, value-type

So, I have a value type :

```
class Session {
    long createdAt;
    List<String> postIds;
}
```

Using the **jedis** client(`3.0.0-m1` is that matters), I am currently performing an `hset` to create the entries and `hgetAll` to retrieve all the key-values:

```
private redis.clients.jedis.Jedis jedis;

void createSession(String idAsKey, Map<String, String> hashFieldValues) {
    jedis.hset(idAsKey, hashFieldValues);
}


Map<String, String> fetchSession(String idAsKey) {
    return jedis.hgetAll(idAsKey);
}
```

The challenge that I am currently looking at is the ease of converting the `Map<String, String>` into the `Session` object. Is there an existing way to do this?

Server response for an equivalent command

> ```
> 1) "createdAt"
> 2) "1556099708307"
> 3) "postIds"
> 4) "[a, b, c]"
> ```

***PS***: Starting to learn Redis, hoping this kind of mapping might have already been solved for. Yes, not looking for a client change as an answer at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jedis doesn't offer a way to map objects to hash structures.

If you are using spring, then you can look at [HashMappers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis.hashmappers.root). A HashMapper converts a POJO to a hash and vice-versa. In your case, the HashMapper will convert a Session to a hash, and the other way round.

Answer (score 3):

You are not using the fields separately, but simultaneously. Because of that, I'd suggest you to use plain and simple [Redis Strings](https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro#redis-strings) instead of using Redis Hashes. So you'd be using `set` to save entries and `get` to retrieve them.

Using above suggestions, your code may become as follows:

```
private redis.clients.jedis.Jedis jedis;
private com.google.gson.Gson gson; // see Note

void createSession(String idAsKey, Session object) {
    String serializedValue = gson.toJson(object);
    jedis.set(idAsKey, serializedValue);
}

Session fetchSession(String idAsKey) {
    String serializedValue = jedis.get(idAsKey);
    Session deserializedObject = gson.fromJson(serializedValue, Session.class);
    return deserializedObject;
}
```

Note: I have used [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) for the purpose of serialization/deserialization. Needless to say, you can use any library.

Answer (score 2):

You can [convert the map to POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428817/convert-a-mapstring-string-to-a-pojo)

```
Session session = new ObjectMapper().convertValue(map, Session.class);
```

So you don't need a special handling expect using a mapper library as [Jackson-Databind](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#convertValue%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Class%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can save and fetch the data to and from Redis like below:

```
public Map<String, Object> saveDataInRedis(String id, Object obj) {
        Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        String jsonObj = "";
        try {
            jsonObj = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
            System.out.println(jsonObj);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException jpe) {
            logger.warn("In saveDataInRedis Exception :: "+jpe);
        }
        try {
            valOps.set(id, jsonObj);
            result.put(DataConstants.IS_SUCCESS, true);
            result.put(DataConstants.MESSAGE, "Data saved succesfully in redis");
        }catch(RedisConnectionFailureException e){
            result =null;
            logger.warn("In saveDataInRedis Exception e :: "+e);
        }
        System.out.println(valOps.getOperations().getClass());
        System.out.println(jedisConnectionFactory.getPoolConfig().getMaxTotal());
        return result;
    }
```

Now get data from redis:

```
public Map<String, Object> getDataFromRedis(String id) {
        Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        String jsonObj = valOps.get(id);
        System.out.println("jsonObj :: " + jsonObj);
        Session obj = null;
        try {
            obj = (Session) objectMapper.readValue(jsonObj, Session.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            result.put("data", null);
            logger.warn("Data from redis is deleted");
            logger.warn("In getDataFromRedis Exception e :: "+e);
        }

        if (obj != null) {
            result.put(DataConstants.IS_SUCCESS, true);
            result.put("data", obj);
        }
        System.out.println("result :: " + result);
        return result;

    }
```