# Converting map to POJO with Jackson ObjectMapper throws exception

Tags: jackson, objectmapper

I have a `MultivaluedMap<String, String>` which represents the form parameters of a POST request. I'd like to convert a POJO from this class with only those fields I need for further processing. I found some answers which suggest using `convertValue()` from the Jackson `ObjectMapper`.

[Convert a Map<String, String> to a POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428817/convert-a-mapstring-string-to-a-pojo)

```
public void process(MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParams) {
  ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
  final MyPojo myPojo = objectMapper.convertValue(formParams,MyPojo.class);
}
```

#### POJO

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MyPojo {

    private String status;

    @JsonProperty("order_no")
    private String orderId;

    @JsonProperty("tid")
    private String transactionId;
}
```

However this fails with the following exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: MyPojo["order_no"])
```

This is how the input looks like in the debugger:

[image: Debugger screenshot]

Comment: Can you show the input?

Comment: Added a screenshot of the debugger. Maybe it's because I use a `MultivaluedMap` instead of a `Map`?

Comment: `order_no` is a list and not a string

Answer (score 0):

I need to replace the `String` type with `ArrayList<String>` which seems to work:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)

public class MyPojo {

    private ArrayList<String> status;

    @JsonProperty("order_no")
    private ArrayList<String> orderId;

    @JsonProperty("tid")
    private ArrayList<String> transactionId;
}
```