# Java convert to a list of objects from JSON

Tags: java, data-binding, fasterxml

I am using Java 7.  I also use `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.objectmapper` to convert json to a Java object.

When I initially convert the the Java object to JSON, I do the following:

```
List<QuoteDTO> selectedQuoteDTOs = ...
String jsonSelectedQuoteDTOs = mapper.writeValueAsString(selectedQuoteDTOs);
```

When I convert the JSON back to a JAVA object I do the following:

```
List<QuoteDTO> selectedQuoteDTOs = mapper.readValue(jsonSelectedQuoteDTOs, List.class);
```

However the `selectedQuoteDTOs` are not of type `QuoteDTO`, but of rather of `LinkedHashMap`.

Resulting in me getting the following error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast
> to com.abc.model.QuoteDTO

when I do this:

```
for (QuoteDTO selectedQuoteDTO : selectedQuoteDTOs) {
```

**Question**

When converting the JSON to JAVA, how do I convert the object to a `List<QuoteDTO>`, instead of a `List<LinkedHashMap>`?

The `LinkedHashMap` keys are the name of the `QuoteDTO` member variables.

Comment: This might be a solution:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428817/convert-a-mapstring-string-to-a-pojo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. This should do the work

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<QuoteDTO> selectedQuoteDTOs = mapper.readValue(jsonSelectedQuoteDTOs, new TypeReference<List<QuoteDTO>>(){});
```