# What is the elegant way to parse a map into an object?

Tags: java

I have a random object and I need to parse Map<String, String>

```
public class ExternalIncome {

    private Long operationId;

    private OffsetDateTime operationDate;

    private String operationCode;

    private String documentNumber;

    private OffsetDateTime documentDate;

    private String correspondentInn;

    private String correspondentName;

    private String correspondentAccount;
}
```

I've just created it this way, but I think it's not quite elegant, rather ugly. Also, I need to intercept every iterate of the parsing to hold dynamic fields into Map<String, String> inside of the object.

```
public static ExternalIncome create(Map<String, String> fields) {
        ExternalIncome externalIncome = new ExternalIncome();
        fields.forEach((k, v) -> {
            switch (k) {
                case "OPER_ID":
                    externalIncome.setOperationId(nullableLong(v));
                    break;
                case "OPER_DATE":
                    externalIncome.setOperationDate(Utils.toOffsetDateTime(v));
                    break;
               etc
```

Could you help me to find the best way?

Comment: One possible (but probably not best-performing) solution is to serialize to a JSON string and then deserialize that into your object, using something like Jackson ObjectMapper, or similar offerings from e.g. Gson.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a Map<String, String> to a POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428817/convert-a-mapstring-string-to-a-pojo)

Comment: @DomenicoSibilio Can I intercept every iteration in this converting?

Comment: Why? I mean, for what purpose? What does "to hold dynamic fields" mean? What do you need the interceptor to do?

Comment: @Andreas I do it for CSV parsing, but opencsv supports only static binding. I mean if the object doesn't include a field, put it into map inside of object "fieldName" -> "value"

Comment: @ДенисБурмистров let's put it differently. Let's say you have a map ("fieldName" ,"value"). Do you need simple mapping  as if map has key X  then map it to field X, or it's more complicated? Hard to say without knowing your map structure.

Comment: @SergeiTonoian Yes, I have a map key-value, that includes all fields of object and dynamic fields for business logic. So, I added to the object a map key-value for store that dynamic fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any elegant solution in your case, but you get rid of switch/case by using map where the key is the field name from the fields map and value is BiDirectionalConsumer. Probably not the best solution, but still. Note: be careful with casts and type conversions.

Let's say you have fields map:

```
Map<String, String> fields = new HashMap<>();   
fields.put("OPER_ID", "3");
```

You can define the second map with field names and operation you want to perform:

```
HashMap<String, BiConsumer<ExternalIncome, Object>> fieldsOperations = new HashMap<>();
fieldsOperations.put("OPER_ID", (extIncome, valueToSet) -> 
    extIncome.setOperationId(Long.valueOf((String) valueToSet))); //add as many as you want
```

And then where you iterate over your map with fields:

```
ExternalIncome externalIncome = new ExternalIncome();
fields.forEach((k,v) -> {        
    BiConsumer<ExternalIncome, Object> operation = fieldsOperations.get(k);
    if (operation == null) {    
        //add to dynamic fields map    
        return;
    }
    operation.accept(externalIncome, v);    
});
```

Or you can reconsider your data structure to get rid of the idea to have dynamic fields, but idk if it's possible with your use case.

Comment: Thanks, it's better, than this
 default:
                    if (v != null) {
                        externalIncome.getTradeObjectRelations().put(tradeObjectId, v);
                    }

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using Jackson's ObjectMapper class , if you are allowed to use third part library.

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
final ExternalIncome income = mapper.convertValue(fields,ExternalIncome.class)
```

Comment: keys in the map and POJO's fields names don't match, so OP has to use @JsonProperty annotation as well

Comment: Can I intercept every iterate of the converting?