# Deserialize Map<String, String> to value of type ArrayList<Object>

Tags: java, jackson

Here is the POJO i am using

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class FileTypes implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @JsonProperty(required = true)
    private FileType name;
    private String status;
    private String namingStrategy;
}
```

I am mapping `Map<String, String>` to `List<FileTypes>`.

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 List<FileTypes> files = mapper.convertValue(newMap, new TypeReference<List<FileTypes>>() {
            });
```

[image]

I am getting the below exception

```
Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<>` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
```

Comment: Post json response

Comment: I dont have a json response, i am using spring cloud config server, which directly maps to   a Map, I am using the map to convert to objects and the client application is a non spring boot app. Just using config client jar.

Comment: So you get a single JSON object like {key: value} and you want it to be converted into a List like [{key:value}] ?

Comment: @aksappy i want to map it to a specific wrapping object i.e `List<Filetypes>` here. reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428817/convert-a-mapstring-string-to-a-pojo

Comment: Can you show the source JSON?

Comment: Is this right, you have this ugly map with keys like "fileTypes[0].name". I think an ObjectMapper can't do that for you...

Comment: @Turo it can convert from map to POJO, I am just thinking there might be a way to handle List<POJO>. please see the reference in comments

Comment: Yes, but ONE Pojo with the keys of the map  named like the members of the Pojo

Comment: @aksappy my source is a yml config file, spring cloud config client receives the file and maps it directly to `Environment.class` its successfully mapped, since my client app is non spring boot. I don't see the source yml being useful since I already have a Map. I checked if spring cloud server could deliver me the entire file but was unsuccessful. Before externalizing my configs i was using YamlMapper and configs were placed in classpath worked fine.

Comment: Oh, in that case, what is the parent key to this map of objects?

Comment: @aksappy i don't know what do you mean by parent key. Each map entry key contains entire key.

Comment: you could parse these key/values "filesTypes[6].name":"EU" into a Map<Integer,Map<String,String>>, with that you could work.