# How to convert a map to a entity object in java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, class, spring-mvc, hashmap

I have a entity object like this:

```
class Person{
 private String name;
 private String class;
 private String semester;
}
```

Now I have a map like this: `Map<String,String>`

```
{
   "name":"Giri"
   "class":"12"
   "semester":"C"
}
```

Now I want to convert this map to a Person object where each field in object corresponds to that field in map.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write your custom mapper for this.

```
toPerson(Map<String, String> map) {
    if(map == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setName = map.get("name");
    person.setClass = map.get("class");
    person.setSemester = map.get("semester");
    return person;
}
```

Or you can use jackson convertValue()

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
Person person = mapper.convertValue(map, Person.class);
```

Apart from jackson's ObjectMapper there are DozerBeanMapper, BeanUtils, google's Gson can be used for same purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer,one doubt though,what if the field that is present in person object is not available in map? is there a default value thats get set?

Comment: Yes default value for according to data type, int = 0, boolean = false. If you have unknown properties in the map, in that case you have to add objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

Comment: but if you writing your custom mapper in that case if property is not there in map, it will be assigned null values or depends on your implementation.

Comment: yes, only if you write your custom implementation.

Comment: This link might help you too, which is an old thread that has few approved answers... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428817/convert-a-mapstring-string-to-a-pojo