# How to convert MultikeyMap to java objects

Tags: java, jackson, pojo

I have a multikey map. Though it's a long map, but for understanding I am just showing 3 elements with 4 fields each.
key1 and key2 are keys for this multikey map.

**Map:**

```
{MultiKey[M3, M33]=Row(field1=2021-02-28, field2=3,key1=M3,key2=M33), MultiKey[M1, M11]=Row(field1=2021-02-28, field2=3,key1=M1,key2=M11), MultiKey[M2, M22]=Row(field1=2021-02-28, field2=2, key1=M2,key2=M22))}
```

My POJO class looks like:

```
@Data
@ToString
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Row implements Serializable {
    public String field1;
    public String field2;
    public String key1;
    public String key2;

    public String toString() {
         return new ToStringBuilder(this).
           append("field1", field1).
           append("field2", field2).
           append("key1", key1).
           append("key2", key2).
           toString();
    }
}
```

I want to convert values of this map to objects. I am trying to do it in below way.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // jackson's objectmapper
Row[] pojo1 = mapper.convertValue(map.values(), Row[].class);
```

I went through https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ToStringBuilder.html as suggested in the comments.

**System.out.println("MATCH KEY1: +ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(pojo1[0].key1));**

```
MATCH KEY1: java.lang.String@372ea2bc[value={M,3},hash=2438]
```

But I expect it to print just M3.

Comment: Looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428817/convert-a-mapstring-string-to-a-pojo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a Map<String, String> to a POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428817/convert-a-mapstring-string-to-a-pojo)

Comment: No, I had a look at this question before asking another one. My requirement is to create pojo for values of a Multikeymap. Unfortunately that solution didn't help me.

Comment: ok. The reason `println` prints `[Lcom.abc.project.models.Row;@32232e55` is because you have not implemented the [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#toString\(\)) method. You can get it auto generated : https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ToStringBuilder.html or https://www.projectlombok.org/features/ToString

Comment: @pyb: I used - System.out.println(ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(map3)); but it gave me result like - org.apache.commons.collections.map.MultiKeyMap@c65a5ef[map=org.apache.commons.collections.map.HashedMap@770d4269]

Comment: Not on your map, on the row like the example you provided. You wanted to verify the conversion right? You can also set a breakpoint and start the debugger (it's fun) or write a simple unit test such as `assertEquals("hello", row.getStringOne())`

Comment: @pyb:   Sorry, It was my bad. I wanted to print pojo1 instead of map. I put the breakpoint and printed pojo1 as well. My all elements are visible. But I am struggling to access those. There is no get method coming for me to access those. In my question, I gave my updated Pojo class as well . Do you see where am I missing something?

Comment: your POJO fields are public so you can call pojo1.field1 directly. Otherwise you need to add getters. Like toString, you can either write them yourselves or use a tool like Lombok and add the annotation `@Data` or `@Getters` on top of your class (right before `public class Pojo`).

Comment: Could you please update the result of println and what you expect versud what you get?

Comment: @pyb: I update my pojo class, and print statement output. Can you please go through it and suggest if any possible solution is there

Comment: @pyb : Expected: M3,  Actual: java.lang.String@372ea2bc[value={M,3},hash=2438]